# Sanitizing POST data in AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm sending AJAX request with POST params (without JQuery). Is there any function to sanitize characters like &?

Comment: `encodeURI` should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really don't need to do that in a [modern browser](http://caniuse.com/#search=xhr2):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.open("POST","yourURL");
xhr.onload = function(data){ /*onload hook */};
xhr.send({keyval:"data here"}); // data here!
```

As you can see, you can pass an object to the `.send` method and it'll send that, you don't need to encode or mess with URI components in the POST body (or GET url) at all.

<sup>you can of course also send form data</sup>

Comment: Also, actually sanitizing/cleaning (as in 'securing and making trustworthy') the data should _always_ be done at the server side. You can never trust the integrity of data that comes from client code.

Comment: This is totally wrong. You can't pass a plain object to `xhr.send()`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is something like this:

[encodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean sanitize or encode?  If encode is what you mean, use:

```
encodeURIComponent(value);
```

in your script, and to decode this in PHP use:

```
urldecode($_POST['key']);
```

to decode the value.  If you meant sanitize, please elaborate.

Comment: You don't need to use `urldecode()` in PHP. It's done automatically when filling in `$_POST`.