# How to post a JavaScript object where each object item becomes a $_POST row with xmlhttprequest?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

**This is not a duplicate of [Send POST data using XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/send-post-data-using-xmlhttprequest).**

---

I would like to post a JavaScript object in JS. I already read the following questions :

- [Sanitizing POST data in AJAX request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21587648/sanitizing-post-data-in-ajax-request)
- [Send javascript object with AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37919270/send-javascript-object-with-ajax)
- [How to send javascript object with POST XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26974503/how-to-send-javascript-object-with-post-xmlhttprequest)
- [Send POST data using XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/send-post-data-using-xmlhttprequest).

None answer to my question since I would like each item of my JS object becomes a $_POST row. Here is an example:

```
myObj = { key1:'value1', 'key2':'value2' }

r = new XMLHttpRequest();
r.onreadystatechange = callBack;
r.open('POST', url, 'async');
r.send(myObj);
```

Server side code:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

On server side, I would like to get from PHP:

- `$_POST['key1']` set to 'value1'
- `$_POST['key2']` set to 'value2'

Instead, `$_POST` is empty.

Note that the previous code works when sending string as:

r.send("key=value");

What's strange is that the [link above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21587648/sanitizing-post-data-in-ajax-request) says it should work but it does not however although I'm using a modern browser.

Comment: tag your question better - this is mostly php related

Comment: Please don't SHOUT, it's considered rude. Also "does not work" is not a very good problem description, please take some time to refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please don't forget how to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: Yes, it works with r.send("key=label");

Comment: This is mostly php related => Seriously ???

Comment: how you send it vs how you get it, yes

Comment: Could you provide server-side code, please?

Comment: I edit the question.

Comment: You aren't treating the post response in your ajax call, how do you know this didn't work ?

Comment: @Cid, the callBack function displays .responseText.

Comment: If you think your previous question was closed incorrectly, you should edit it to clarify and then ask for it to be reopened. Don't post an identical question.

Comment: @Temmu I alread read all the answers. None exactly answer to my question. I want to send a object and receive the object in $_POST. I don't want to send JSON or other stuff, I know how to do that. This is not my question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer you linked to is wrong, it shouldn't have been accepted.

Comment: @Barmar, this is also what I'm thinking. StackOverflow refuses my great questions, and accepts wrong answers :-) Nice revange.

Comment: There are 18 answers ... Anyway, you can't pass a live JS object, http can transfer text only. A simple way is to use ex. FormData object.

Comment: @miken, yes and I clearly do not understand why this question has been closed. "This question is of topic", Are you kidding me ? Could you explain why the question is off topic ?

Comment: @miken By the way, the link you mentioned as duplicate is absolutely not duplicated, this is not the same question. I read carefully both of them. Did you read the questions/answer before posting your comment or event marking this question as "off topic" ? I absolutely don't understand you guys.

Comment: Why the question is closed? Everything is clear, I would like to post an alternative answer with FormData.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you linked to that says you can send the object in `r.send()` is wrong. The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) says that the argument to `r.send()` must be:

> - A `Document`, in which case it is serialized before being sent.
> - A `BodyInit`, which as per the Fetch spec can be a `Blob`, `BufferSource`, `FormData`, `URLSearchParams`, `ReadableStream`, or `USVString` object.

A plain object is not any of these.

You should convert the object to one of those types, and URL-encoded strings are generally used for ordinary data (`FormData` is generally only used when you need to upload files).

```
var params = Object.entries(myObj).map((key, val) => encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(val))
    .join('&');
r.send(params);
```

Comment: Why not using a [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/FormData) ? (from your answer, "you *should* ..." could be "you *can* ...")

Comment: I've clarified that this is the usual type for ordinary strings.